# Why are some of my inputs considered nodes and others arent'?

Tags: javascript

I have a task where I need to dynamically generate inputs for time intervals. I can generate the intervals, but when I try to attach the inputs to a form to submit, the even indices of the inputs are considered as nodes, but I get an error saying append child does not work for a non node. Why are some being considered as nodes and others aren't?

Dont mind the if statement always executing, I removed some error checking to see if that was the issue. Sorry if this is a stupid question. I haven't used javascript before.

````
   function validateForm() {
               var container, inputs, index, flag;
               flag = 0;
               container = document.getElementById('container');
               inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
               form = document.createElement('form');
               if (flag == 0) {
                   form.appendChild(inputs);
                   document.body.appendChild(form);
                   form.submit();
                   alert("Your schedule has been validated and saved! Go to View Schedule to see your new schedule, or Upload Schedule to push it to the Scheduler");
               }
           }
           function addFields() {
               var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
               if (number > 24) {
                   number = 24;
               } else if (number < 1) {
                   number = 0;
               }
               var container = document.getElementById("container");
               while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                   container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
               }
               if (number > 0) {
                   container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Start" + "\u2002".repeat(8) + "End"));
                   container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
               }
               for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                   var input = document.createElement("input");
                   input.type = "time";
                   input.name = "start" + i;
                   container.appendChild(input);
                   container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
               }
               if (number > 0) {
                   var x = document.createElement("button");
                   x.innerHTML = "Save";
                   container.appendChild(x);
                   x.addEventListener("click", validateForm);
               }
           }
       
   ```
````

Comment: what line is it occurring on and what is the exact error message?

Comment: `inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');` and `form.appendChild(inputs);` <-- trying to append an html collection, not a single node.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node" It occurs at "form.appendChild(inputs);" in the first function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `appendChild` expects a single node but you aren't passing it a single node. You will want to loop through the inputs and append them each, also use querySelectorAll

```
inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(input){
   form.appendChild(input)
})
```